# Azure Web App (Linux Nginx) - where are the php errors logged to by default?

Tags: php, azure, error-handling

I have built a Bootstrap 5 web app on Azure Web App (Linux Nginx, PHP 8). I want to know - by default where are the php errors logged to?

For development I have turned on all error reporting in my config.php file with these lines of code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I know that error logging is turned on because with the following line, I can write errors to the file myRootDirectory/error_log":

```
error_log("My custom error message", 3, "myRootDirectory/error_log");
```

However this is cumbersome. I want a way to catch all errors in a log file. I tried the following line in my config.php file but that does not work either. With the below configuration I would expect all other errors and warnings to be written to myRootDirectory/error_log, but they are not:

```
ini_set("error_log", "myRootDirectory/error_log");
```

So back to my question - where are the errors being logged by default?

Thank you